# Yii2 Active Record Не могу получить в выборке поле из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

День добрый!
Не могу получить в выборке поле из связанной таблицы "Clinics". Пытаюсь получить вот так:

```
 public function actionOpinionsjson() {
    $one = ClinicOpinions::find()
        ->select(['id', 'text', 'clinic->name'])
        ->with('clinic')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $one;
}
```

Не получается.

А если вот такой код, без условий на отображаемые поля, то данные из связанной таблицы попадают.

```
public function actionOpinionsjson()
{
    $one = ClinicOpinions::find()
        ->with('clinic')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $one;
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема как раз и заключалась в вашей выборке, в методе `select` вы передаете данные так как их будет подставлять в запрос скрипт, а к примеру в MySQL нет такой выборки `clinic->name`, используйте вот такой вариант:

```
 public function actionOpinionsjson() {
    $one = ClinicOpinions::find()
        ->select(['id', 'text', 'clinic.name'])
        ->with('clinic')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $one;
}
```

Comment: Не работает, Mysql так-же думает, что Unknown column 'clinic.name' in 'field list'

Comment: @rud99 какой запрос он генерирует?

Comment: вот, видно, что поле не то попадает "SELECT `id`, `text`, `clinic`.`name` FROM `clinic_opinions`" а вот связь     public function getClinic()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Clinics::className(), ['id' => 'clinic_id']);
    }

Comment: @rud99 попробуйте `with` на `joinWith` заменить

Comment: Вот этод код         $one = ClinicOpinions::find()
            ->with(['clinic' => function ($query) { $query->select('name');}])
            ->asArray()
            ->all(); Генерирует 2 таких запроса: SELECT * FROM `clinic_opinions` и  SELECT `name` FROM `clinics` WHERE `id` IN ('1', '3')

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionOpinionsjson()
{
    $one = ClinicOpinions::find()
        ->select(['id', 'text', 'clinic_id'])
        ->with(['clinic'=>function($q){ $q->select(['name']) }])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $one;
}
```

или

```
$one = ClinicOpinions::find()
    ->select(['id', 'text', 'clinic_id', Clinic::tableName().'.name'])
    ->joinWith('clinic')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Comment: код выше уже пробовал раньше, он выполняет только вот этот запрос: SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `clinic_opinions`

Comment: В общем то он должен два запроса сгенерировать, можно еще `with` на `joinWith` заменить, должен один создать

Comment: Мда, что то я тоже забыл, вам то для связи нужен ключ, а где вы его выбираете? Верно, нигде, вот и результат - никакой, изменил ответ, но тут бы уже связь знать надо

Comment: Вот связь есть  public function getClinic()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Clinics::className(), ['id' => 'clinic_id']);
    }

Comment: изменил ответ, проверьте